How to Specify Table Dimensions for a .docx file
I have a flextable object that I want to export as a .docx file with specific dimensions (height=3.43 inches, width=6.86 inches). I can export my flextable as a .docx file, but I can't figure out how to specify the dimensions of the table.
#reading in data
data<-mtcars
  
#creating the flextable
ft<-flextable(data[1:8,1:8])

#saving table as a .docx
ft %>% save_as_docx(path = "./images/tables/test.docx", height=3.43, width=6.86, unit="in")

This code will save my flextable as a .docx file, but the table is not the right dimensions (3.43 x 6.86). Is there any way to do this in R? Thanks!

Does changing the default flextable arguments   cwidth = 0.75 cheight = 0.25 achieve what you are looking for?

I've tried adding the cwidth and cheight arguments like so: ft<-flextable(data[1:8,1:8],cheight=(3.43/9),cwidth=(6.86/8)). This doesn't seem to change the final table dimensions though.
